# Inputmask el groupSeparator: ',', no me esta funcionando

Tags: javascript, c#

Intento que me aparezca la coma, y no lo hace

li = li + "$(function(){$('#modal-additional-" + item.Id + "').inputmask('numeric', {allowPlus: false, allowMinus: false, rightAlign: true, groupSeparator: ',',  numericInput: true, radixPoint: '.', digits: 2, unmaskAsNumber: true}); }); <*script>".replace("<*", "</");
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]